# Numbers having a unique partition into three nonnegative triangular numbers

Tags: number-theory, triangular-numbers

The sequence of numbers having a unique partition into three nonnegative triangular numbers is on https://oeis.org/A060773. Is it proven (where?) that there is no such number greater than 53?

Comment: The OEIS entry does contain keywords `fini` and `full`. I don't know the exact meaning, but an educated guess of their meaning would be that the list is known to be complete. I may be wrong, but representing $M$ as  a sum of three triangular numbers is equivalent to representing $8M+3$ as a sum of three squares (necessarily all odd). May be that version is easier to find? $8\cdot53+3=427$ is the largest integer $\equiv3\pmod8$ such that its representation as a sum of 3 squares is unique?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Exactly! Then the proof is here: <https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/81998833.pdf> Thank you very much.